Bidirectional RPC stream closure
I  noticed some asymmetry for bidirectional RPC stream closure between RPC stream server and RPC stream client.
onCompleted()

If RPC stream client sends onCompleted(), RPC stream server will receive onCompleted(). RPC streams is closed on client->server direction. RPC stream server could still send messages to RPC stream client.
If RPC stream server sends onCompleted(), RPC stream client will receive onCompleted(). However,  RPC stream client could no longer send messages to RPC stream server. It seems that entire stream has been closed.

onError()

If RPC stream client sends onError(), both RPC stream client and RPC stream server will received onError()
If RPC stream server sends onError(), only RPC stream client will received onError()

Is this expected?
I expect that RPC stream server sends onCompleted(), it will not close the entire stream.
I expect that RPC stream server sends onError(), it will also receive onError().
public class GrpcPlayground {
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setName("grpc-client-thread");
        return t;
    });

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setName("schedule-service-thread");
        return t;
    });

    private static final boolean IS_LINUX = SystemUtil.osName().startsWith("linux");
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 50051;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new GrpcPlayground().run();
    }

    private ManagedChannel managedChannel;
    private NettyServerBuilder grpcServerBuilder;
    private Server server;

    void run() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        grpcServerBuilder = NettyServerBuilder
                .forPort(SERVER_PORT)
                .directExecutor()
                .channelType(IS_LINUX ? EpollServerSocketChannel.class : NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .bossEventLoopGroup(IS_LINUX ? new EpollEventLoopGroup(1) : new NioEventLoopGroup(1))
                .workerEventLoopGroup(IS_LINUX ? new EpollEventLoopGroup(2) : new NioEventLoopGroup(2))
                .withChildOption(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 256 * 1024)
                .withChildOption(ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, 256 * 1024)
                .withChildOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);

        managedChannel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", SERVER_PORT)
                .withOption(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 2 * 1024 * 1024)
                .withOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                .usePlaintext()
                .directExecutor()
                .disableRetry()
                .build();

        server = grpcServerBuilder.addService(new HelloServiceGrpc.HelloServiceImplBase() {
            @Override
            public StreamObserver<HelloServiceProto.HelloRequest> bidiHello(StreamObserver<HelloServiceProto.HelloResponse> responseObserver) {
                ServerCallStreamObserver<HelloServiceProto.HelloResponse> serverCallStreamObserver =
                        (ServerCallStreamObserver<HelloServiceProto.HelloResponse>) responseObserver;
                serverCallStreamObserver.setOnCancelHandler(() -> {
                    System.out.printf("server rpc got cancelled, threadName: %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                });


                return new StreamObserver<HelloServiceProto.HelloRequest>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(HelloServiceProto.HelloRequest value) {
                        System.out.printf("server got request, threadName: %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        System.out.println("server sent onCompleted()");
                        responseObserver.onCompleted();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        Status status = Status.fromThrowable(t);
                        System.out.printf("server got error. status: %s, threadName: %s%n", status.getCode(), Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        try {
                            System.out.println("server sent onNext()");
                            responseObserver.onNext(HelloServiceProto.HelloResponse.newBuilder().build());
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            System.out.println("server sent onNext() throws exception");
                        }
                        try {
                            System.out.println("server sent onCompleted()");
                            responseObserver.onCompleted();
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            System.out.println("server sent onCompleted() throws exception");
                        }
                        try {
                            System.out.println("server sent onError()");
                            responseObserver.onError(new RuntimeException("test"));
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            System.out.println("server sent onError() throws exception");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        System.out.printf("server got onCompleted, threadName: %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    }
                };
            }
        }).build().start();


        HelloServiceGrpc.HelloServiceStub stub = HelloServiceGrpc.newStub(managedChannel).withExecutor(executorService);
        HelloServiceProto.HelloRequest request = HelloServiceProto.HelloRequest.newBuilder().build();
        StreamObserver<HelloServiceProto.HelloRequest> streamObserver = stub.bidiHello(
                new StreamObserver<HelloServiceProto.HelloResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(HelloServiceProto.HelloResponse value) {
                        System.out.printf("client got response, threadName: %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        Status status = Status.fromThrowable(t);
                        System.out.printf("client got error. status: %s, threadName: %s%n", status.getCode(), Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        System.out.printf("client got onCompleted, threadName: %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    }
                });

        System.out.println("client sent request");
        streamObserver.onNext(request);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        try {
            System.out.println("client sent onNext");
            streamObserver.onNext(request);
            System.out.println("client sent onCompleted");
            streamObserver.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("client calls onError() throws exception");
        }

        Thread.sleep(10000000);
        managedChannel.shutdownNow();
        server.shutdownNow();
    }
}

This is output:

